# Find Coefficient in expansion

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> What will be the coefficient of $x^8$ in the expansion of $x^2\cos x^2$ around $x=0$?
>
> I know that it can be done using Leibniz formula for higher order diferentiation of product of two functions ,But is there any shorter method?

Comment: if you know the expansion of $\cos x$ you can plug in $x^2$ then multiply by $x^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

We [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) $$\cos y=1-\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^4}{4!}-\frac{y^6}{6!}+\cdots$$

$$\implies \cos x^2=1-\frac{x^4}{2!}+\frac{x^8}{4!}-\frac{x^{12}}{6!}+\cdots$$

The coefficient of $x^8$ in the expansion of $x^2\cos x^2$

$=$ The coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion of $\cos x^2$ which is zero

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(x)=1-\frac{{x}^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{4}}{4!}-...$

so

$\cos(x^{2})=1-\frac{{x}^{4}}{2!}+\frac{x^{8}}{4!}-...$

so

$x^{2}\cos(x^{2})=x^{2}-\frac{{x}^{6}}{2!}+\frac{x^{10}}{4!}-...$

Thus the coefficient of $x^{8}$ is $0$.